# how we set marker label content by javascript in google map api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using this code this code to change label text of marker label in google map api. But this code not working.

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position : latlng,
        draggable : true,
        raiseOnDrag : true,
        map : map,
        labelContent : textVal,
        labelAnchor : new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
        title : "" + textCount,
        labelClass : "someClass" + textCount,
        icon:{}
    });
    marker.setLabelContent("sdda");
```

please can anybody let me know what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
marker.set('labelContent', 'sdda');
```

Reading through the [marker label source code](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/src/markerwithlabel.js), the MarkerLabel object extends from google.maps.Marker.

Whenever you call the `.set()` method on the MarkerLabel object, an event is raised which refreshes the marker.

So calling `marker.set('labelContent', 'sdda');` will raise a `'labelcontent_changed'` event, which in turn makes the marker set it's inner content `this.setContent()`

Here is an excerpt from the source code:

@class This class represents the optional parameter passed to the {@link MarkerWithLabel} constructor.
The properties available are the same as for `google.maps.Marker` with the addition of the properties listed below. To change any of these additional properties after the labeled
marker has been created, call `google.maps.Marker.set(propertyName, propertyValue)`.

Comment: just for modern users, you would currently use 'label' instead of 'labelContent'

Answer (score 1):

Try:
var label= { color: '#333', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '16px', text: data[i].deviceID.toUpperCase() };
marker.setLabel(label);

Comment: Thanks for the answer.it helps me a lot